# forcing pyYAML to dump consistently

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

```py
In [136]: a = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [137]: print yaml.dump(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


In [138]: a = [1,2,3,4,5, [1,2,3]]

In [139]: print yaml.dump(a)
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- [1, 2, 3]
```

why are the outputs of above two `dumps` different? Is it possible to force `pyYAML` to split the `list` always?

Comment: What are you expecting the output to look like?  The corresponding dump of this python list looks fine in yaml format.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#DumpingYAML):

```
print yaml.dump(a, default_flow_style=False)
```

The value can be `True`, `False`, or `None`. If `None` or unspecified (that is, the default), it chooses automatically whether to use inline or block-style output. `False` never uses inline, `True` is always inline.

Comment: Yep.  As the first FAQ entry says: "By default, PyYAML chooses the style of a collection depending on whether it has nested collections. If a collection has nested collections, it will be assigned the block style. Otherwise it will have the flow style."

Comment: I can't choose either. I want lists to go out as `[1,2,3]` and dicts to go out in separate lines with indents. How can this be done?