# print multiple YAML lists in a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, printing, yaml

I am new to python programming. The input X.yaml file contains a list of list of dictionaries. I am trying to print the list and it's sub-list items.

Input:X.Yaml

```
    entities:
        - level: undefined
          name: a
          refs:
              - b
          reqs: []
        - level: undefined
          name: c
          refs:
              - b
          reqs: []
```

Code:

```
data = yaml.load(yamlfile)
for entity in data["entities"]:
     #Needed help here.
```

Desired output:

```
-name: a
 refs:
     - b
 reqs: []
-name: c
 refs:
    - b
 reqs: []
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `yaml.dump()` with [`default_flow_style=False`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024915/1431750):

```
>>> print yaml.dump(data['entities'], default_flow_style=False)
- level: undefined
  name: a
  refs:
  - b
  reqs: []
- level: undefined
  name: c
  refs:
  - b
  reqs: []
```

And if you don't want the 'level', then first remove that from the entities:

```
>>> new_entities = [{key: value for key, value in entity.items() if key != 'level'}
...                 for entity in data['entities']]
>>>
>>> print yaml.dump(new_entities, default_flow_style=False)
- name: a
  refs:
  - b
  reqs: []
- name: c
  refs:
  - b
  reqs: []

>>>
```

*Edit: If the list and dictionary comprehensions are confusing, this is the long (and lower performance) way to write it:*

```
>>> new_entities = []
>>> for entity in data['entities']:
...     new_ent = {}
...     for key, value in entity.items():
...         if key != 'level':
...             new_ent[key] = value
...     new_entities.append(new_ent)
...
>>> # then dump `new_entities`
```