# Ansible YAML Output Formatting For List of Dictionaries

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In Ansible, is it possible to output a list of dictionaries in pretty print YAML with flow style mapping?

Example of source list of dict:

```yaml
my_servers:
  - hostname: myhostname1
    id: 101
    reverse: 'true'
    type: red
  - hostname: myhostname2
    id: 102
    reverse: 'false'
    type: white
  - hostname: myhostname3
    id: 103
    reverse: 'true'
    type: blue
  - hostname: myhostname4
    id: 104
    reverse: 'false'
    type: green
```

I'd like to output to be like this:

```yaml
my_servers:
  - {hostname: myhostname1, id: 101, type: red, reverse: "true"}
  - {hostname: myhostname2, id: 102, type: white, reverse: "false"}
  - {hostname: myhostname3, id: 103, type: blue, reverse: "true"}
  - {hostname: myhostname4, id: 104, type: green, reverse: "false"}
```

The only way I got it to look like this was through custom Jinja templating. Is there another way someone can share?

Comment: Possible non-answer pointer: Ansible `to_yaml` uses the lib [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) and you can pass the arguments you would pass to the formatting of the library to the filter. So, if there is a way to do it with the library PyYAML, then it can be applied here.

Comment: And then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024783/forcing-pyyaml-to-dump-consistently. But his also swap the list style into a flow style, of course.

Comment: Why do you need this, if I may ask? Is it only for display purpose?

Comment: Thank you. I've already look at `to_yaml` and `to_nice_yaml`. It seems to only allow for width, indentation adjustments. Yeah mainly for display purposes - we write back to Git repo and makes it easier to read, edit and maintain. This becomes especially useful when we have a few hundred items in the list.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε - you did it! Thanks. I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@β.εηοιτ.βε above led to dig further and found the answer.

The key is to set default_flow_style=none in the to_yaml filter.

```yaml
- name: Test
  hosts: "localhost"
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1

  vars:
    my_servers:
      - hostname: myhostname1
        id: 101
        reverse: 'true'
        type: red
      - hostname: myhostname2
        id: 102
        reverse: 'false'
        type: white
      - hostname: myhostname3
        id: 103
        reverse: 'true'
        type: blue
      - hostname: myhostname4
        id: 104
        reverse: 'false'
        type: green

  tasks:
  - debug: 
      msg: | 
        my_servers:
        {{  my_servers | to_yaml(default_flow_style=none) }}
```

Gives this:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

my_servers:
- {hostname: myhostname1, id: 101, reverse: 'true', type: red}
- {hostname: myhostname2, id: 102, reverse: 'false', type: white}
- {hostname: myhostname3, id: 103, reverse: 'true', type: blue}
- {hostname: myhostname4, id: 104, reverse: 'false', type: green}
```

The problem now is to get proper indentation.

Comment: `{{  my_servers | to_yaml(default_flow_style=none) | indent(2, True) }}`, then.